# Exclamation mark inside triggerHandler

Tags: jquery

In the Jquery source code, there is a line

```
data = this.triggerHandler("getData" + parts[1] + "!", [parts[0]]);
```

`parts[1]` can be an empty string, but what does `"!"` do here? what kind of event will it trigger? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The exclamation mark means that only event handlers without a namespace will be triggered.

From this [jQuery ticket](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13873)

> Those were called "exclusive events" but were never documented. They were removed in jQuery 1.9.

Comment: FYI, the only "official" reference I can find to it is here: http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13873 It seems it was removed in 1.9